# javascript setInterval function not working

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function for every half minute. i am using the following code. The function is not getting triggered.

Code:

```
window.setInterval('progress()', 10000);
```

Geetha.

Comment: 10000 milliseconds is 10 seconds...
Does the function progress exist?

Comment: now i am using this code window.setInterval(progress(), 10000);
function getting executed but not after the time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every half min would be 30,000 miliseconds

Example ...

```
refreshId = setInterval(myfunction(), 30000);
```

In jQuery you'd do something like ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var refreshId = setInterval(myfunction(), 30000);

});
```

Or if you want to put your function within your refresh code ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#myid").load('/mypage.html?update='+ Math.random());
    }, 30000);

});
```

Comment: This is wrong... it will call `myfunction()` as part of the setup of the interval, and use the return value.  It should be providing a reference to `myfunction` instead: `setInterval(myfunction,30000);`

Answer (score 1):

I think the setInterval method may somehow fail to find the definition of the progress function.

Have you tried invoking setInterval with the function object directly?

```
window.setInterval(progress, 10000);
```